# How to share IDE layout in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, ide, projects-and-solutions

I'm frequently changing projects and creating new ones, but I have a big a project that I work on a lot. The IDE layout (view positions, sizes and docking) evolves as I use it more and more. **I'm looking for a way to automatically share IDE layout between projects in IDEA?**

I would like to avoid re-setting up my environment every time I do File/New/Project. I also would like to avoid exporting/importing my configuration for every File/New/Project. Handling of updates would be a really nice one too, that is, when I resize the Project/Debug view in one project it changes in all of my projects that are created new or reopened. **Essentially I would like to avoid any repetitive clicking whenever I switch context (project).**

*I'm really used to Eclipse storing the settings tied to the workspace and when a new project is created they have the same settings.*

Comment: agree, this is very annoying. and I'm too lazy to have tried to figure it out. if you have tried and failed to find a solution, time to file a bug to IntelliJ. I find that they are very responsive to user feedbacks.

Comment: There is a menu option [_Window/Store Current Layout as Default_](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/11/devoxx-follow-up-your-ide-can-do-more/). I have not tried it but maybe it could do what you want?

Comment: That sounds close, but I still have to manually save and restore the "default". Which means I have to press save every time I close a project and press load every time I open/create a project.

Comment: @TWiStErRob I'm not aware of any better way. Try creating feature request on youtrack.jetbrains.com to allow automatically sharing window layout between all projects.

Answer (score 3):

The closest functionality that I know of is *Window/Store Current Layout as Default*. It will save the current layout and it will be used for newly created projects.

But when you modify the layout and want to use that version as default, you have to first save it as default using the action mentioned above and then in other projects use *Window/Restore Default Layout* (ie. the changes to default layout won't be saved/applied to other projects automatically).

I would suggest opening a feature request on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com to enable sharing the layout automatically between all projects.

Comment: It's still manual, but I tried this and it kinda' works: some views are not moved to the correct places (e.g. *Terminal* was Bottom-Left when saved, but it restored to Bottom-Right; *Run* was Bottom-Left when saved, restored Top-Left). It also doesn't close extra open Views.

Comment: I'll report back if I open a request in YT.